# Data inserted not retained unless I restart the application

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am using `SQLITE` with my iPhone App. After Inserting the values in the `detailedViewController`, I am reloading the data from the database in the `masterViewController viewWillAppear` method. However I can't get the newly updated row there unless I restart the application.
I am finalizing the complied statement and closing the database after `INSERT`.

```
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Any pointers as to where I might be doing something wrong?

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM MYCAR1";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                //...getting data from compiled statements...

                MyCar *car=[[MyCar alloc] initWithVIN:vin.intValue andMake:make andModel:model andYear:year andColor:color andImageData:image];
                [myArray addObject:car];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        carList=myArray;
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Are you updating your array as well???? are you reloading your table????

Comment: Yes, I'm updating the array and calling the reloadDATA method on the tableView.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I am debugging the code. The select statement just doen't return the new row.

Comment: I'm a newbie here I cant seem to paste my code here..says too long..
Any help?

Comment: show only that code where you are facing difficulty. like while selecting data from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added exact code for selecting, which is working for me. Try to compare this with your code and figure out the error.

```
sqlite3 *database;

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from xxx"];

    const char *sqlStatement=[querySql UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the your array

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)  {
           //get the data from db here                


        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Done. It's still returning all the rows I created before I restarted the application. Doesn't return any new row added unless I restart the app.

Comment: Did the changes, my select statement is returning rows but not the rows from the current context. What I dont understand is while the insert statement is working why is it not reflected when my app is running? Is there a need to commit the statements after the insert? Or do I need to do something when I am reloading the database?
My statement when I am reloading the database:
    NSString *dbPath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAssgn9.db"];

Comment: try to close your db and open again.

Comment: Didn't help :( I am even running the select statement in the terminal to see if the row is inserted properly. It does. Just cant get it from the select. May be the database is not being opened properly again.
Anyway thanks for taking your time to help me. It's 5 in the morning for me and I will have to sleep. :)
Will check back tomorrow to see if I can figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like my problem was the app was getting rows from another db file with the same name when refreshing but was intially getting the values from the original database in     viewDIdLoad. My bad. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @charan i'm proud of u :P he he